# How to access dbms on filter class file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have java/com/site/repository/BookRepository.java
; how to access database book entity in
java/com/site/web/filter/BookFilter.java

i tried

```
@inject
private BookRepository bookRepository
```

but bookRepository is null

thank you

Comment: This is not a JHIpster specific question, this is a spring mvc question. It mainly depends on how you declare your filter. Check their documentation. You may also consider replacing your filter by a spring mvc interceptor.

Comment: ok, thanks for your clue